# Plotting with Python

Tags: python, numpy, plot, matplotlib

I have a .txt file from which I find ordered pairs, and then draw a graphic using numpy and matplotlib. For example these are my ordered pairs:

```
[[(4.0, 0), (0, 6.0)], [(6.0, 0), (0, 3.0)]]
```

(Each sub-list represents a line in the final graphic)

The graphic looks like this:

[image: grafik1]

But I want to find the intersection between the two lines.
And if there were more lines, how can I find the common area between them all? e.g.

[image: grafik2]

Comment: Hi Schoolboy, in your second question are you referring to the area in the first quadrant under all the lines? If you only have two lines, there would be no "common area between all the intersections", since there only would be one.

Comment: @user Yes, maybe you meant enclosed with some other lines like the axes?

Comment: It looks like the URLs to your graphics are no longer valid (they expired).

Comment: @user1305311, the links you posted are giving us an "access denied" error.

Comment: @JonasByström I can have maybe 2 or more lines. All depends on what is written in the .txt file. This is an example with 3 lines. And here I have to find intersection points. Just like this:

http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/6471/ejem4.png

Comment: @JasonSundram Done, I thing images links are working now.

Comment: @blz Done, I thing images links are working now.