# Matplotlib questions

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Plotting with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647500/plotting-with-python)

I've been using Matprolib for plotting. I've found it very useful, but I dont know exactly how to use the 'fill_between()' function. I have tried several times to fix it but I cant get to the point.

I have been studying several tutorials, but I havent found very useful ones (according to my task).

My task is to fill the area that all lines have in common, just like this:

[Whatitshoulddo](http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/8007/noerror.png)

And this is what the system does:

[Whatitshouldntdo](http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/4656/errorfz.png)

Is there any way to do it? Anyone knows how to use 'fill_between()' in a correct way?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10647500/1301710

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `where` option. As in the [example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/fill_between_demo.html) you can do something like:

```
fill_between(x, myzero, y1, where=y2>=y1, facecolor='blue', interpolate=True)
```

Where y2 is the line that is sometimes on top. You will have do do this for each of the lines, though.

Another option is to define a minimum of the functions and fill below that, though you will either need to know before hand that the ys are defined at the same points or use interpolation so that they are all defined at the same points.

```
mymin = np.minimum(y1,y2,y3)
fill_between(x, myzero, mymin)
```

Hope that helps.

Edit: To find the minimum from several functions which are all defined for the same x-values you can use the following:

```
def OverallMinimum(*ys):
    mymin = y[0].copy()
    for y in ys:
        min = np.minimum(mymin,y)
    return mymin
```

Then you can use the second `fill_between` from above to plot between zero and the minimum from that function.

Comment: Yeah that will help a lot.

but I have one more question. The number of lines is not always the same, for example, there can be just two lines, as well as 5 lines. So, how can I have unlimited unlimited number of variables?

Is there any way to do that?
Thanks

Comment: You could write a quick function that finds the minimum from several functions and use the second option. I'll edit to include such a minimum function.

Comment: If you like my answer you could accept it by clicking the check mark.